# SVG Draw a circle with 4 sectors

Tags: html, svg, trigonometry

I need to draw a circle with 4 sectors. I'm trying to draw a sector like this:

```
<path d="M200, 200, l 100,-100 a180,180 0 0,0 -127.27,127.27 z"/>
```

I got the -127.27, 127.27 from the equations:

```
x=cos(angle) * radius
y=sin(angle) * radius
```

My angle is 135, and my radius is 180.

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjKgdY) of what i get. The blue one is the one I'm talking about here, the black one is what I'm trying with different numbers.

Why am i not getting a proper 1/4 of a circle? What am i missing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The numbers don't make much sense. You start by moving to `(200,200)`, then draw a straight line to `(300,100)` (length: 141 units) followed by a circular arc ending at `(172.73,227.27)` (radius 180 units). Shouldn't the length of the straight line segment at least be equal to the radius of the circle?

You're making life terribly difficult for yourself. If you want to draw four circular segments, a good first step would be to use a `<g>` element to move the coordinate system to the centre of the circle. Then you can create all four segments using near-identical code.

Here's an example:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <g transform="translate(100,100)" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2">
    <path d="M0 0-70 70A99 99 0 0 1-70-70Z" fill="#f00"/>
    <path d="M0 0-70-70A99 99 0 0 1 70-70Z" fill="#080"/>
    <path d="M0 0 70-70A99 99 0 0 1 70 70Z" fill="#dd0"/>
    <path d="M0 0 70 70A99 99 0 0 1-70 70Z" fill="#04e"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

If you want a circle with a different radius, replace `99` with the radius you want, and replace `70` with this value times sqrt(0.5).

#### Path data breakdown:

```
M0 0-70 70
```

[Move](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands) to `(0,0)`, then draw a straight line to `(-70,70)` (the `L` is implied).

```
A99 99 0 0 1-70-70
```

Draw an [elliptical arc](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) from this point to `(-70,-70)` with `rx=rx=99`, `x-axis-rotation=0`, `large-arc-flag=1`, and `sweep-flag=0`. (The last two parameters are described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/paths/arcs02.svg)).

```
Z
```

[Close](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataClosePathCommand) the path.

Comment: Could you tell me a bit more, so I can understand what's actually happening? This puts the center in 100,100, right? And what does  M0 0-70 70 do?

Answer (score 12):

i'm realy lazy, so what i do when i need to draw arcs, is i use the following script:
i create a unit vector:

```
var p = svgElem.createSVGPoint()
p.x = 0
p.y = 1
```

then i cerate a matrix for my rotations:

```
var m = svgElem.createSVGMatrix()
```

and finally i rotate the unit vector  and translate/scale it to where i want it.

```
var p2 = p.matrixTransform(m.rotate(45))
p2.x = cx + p2.x*rx
p2.y = cy + p2.y*ry
```

and now i can either `console.log(p2.x,p2.y)` if i want to hardcode the segment, or you can create the segments from script.

here is a basic example (i know, for a simple case like the one above, this is not necessary, but its an easy general solution, which has help me a lot in the past years...)

```js
var svgElem=document.getElementById("svg");
var cx=100;
var cy=100;
var rx=90;
var ry=90;

var p = svgElem.createSVGPoint();
    p.x = 0;
    p.y = 1;


var m = svgElem.createSVGMatrix();


var p2 = p.matrixTransform(m.rotate(45));
    p2.x = cx + p2.x*rx;
    p2.y = cy + p2.y*ry;
    
    console.log(p2.x,p2.y);

var path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","path");
    svgElem.appendChild(path);
var d="M"+cx+" "+(cy+ry)+"A"+rx+" "+ry+" 0 0 1"+p2.x+" "+p2.y+"L"+cx+" "+cy+"z";
    path.setAttribute("d",d)
```

```html
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">
  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is the function which does programmatic generation of `SVG` sector path I used in `React` component:

```
getSectorPath(x, y, outerDiameter, a1, a2) {
    const degtorad = Math.PI / 180;
    const halfOuterDiameter = outerDiameter / 2;
    const cr = halfOuterDiameter - 5;
    const cx1 = (Math.cos(degtorad * a2) * cr) + x;
    const cy1 = (-Math.sin(degtorad * a2) * cr) + y;
    const cx2 = (Math.cos(degtorad * a1) * cr) + x;
    const cy2 = (-Math.sin(degtorad * a1) * cr) + y;

    return "M" + x + " " + y + " " + cx1 + " " + cy1 + " A" + cr + " " + cr + " 0 0 1 " + cx2 + " " + cy2 + "Z";
}
```

and here is the usage:

```
<svg width={outerDiameter} height={outerDiameter}>
    <path d={this.getSectorPath(outerDiameter / 2, outerDiameter / 2, outerDiameter, 45, 135)} fill="#f00"/>
    <path d={this.getSectorPath(outerDiameter / 2, outerDiameter / 2, outerDiameter, 135, 225)} fill="#f00"/>
    <path d={this.getSectorPath(outerDiameter / 2, outerDiameter / 2, outerDiameter, 225, 315)} fill="#f00"/>
    <path d={this.getSectorPath(outerDiameter / 2, outerDiameter / 2, outerDiameter, 315, 45)} fill="#f00"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: very usefull function, i would change only last line to:

`return \`M${x} ${y} ${cx1} ${cy1} A${cr} ${cr} 0 0 1 ${cx2} ${cy2}Z\`;`

Answer (score 1):

This is the example where I create svg from JavaScript. I wrote it inspired by @zmechanic answer. One sector has gradient.
To execute it just create an html document and copy the content.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="svgRoot"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const DIAMETER = 200;
      const SVG_SIZE = DIAMETER + 12;
      const STROKE = "black";
      const STROKE_WIDTH = "2";

      const getSectorPath = (x, y, outerDiameter, a1, a2) => {
        const degtorad = Math.PI / 180;
        const cr = outerDiameter / 2;
        const cx1 = Math.cos(degtorad * a2) * cr + x;
        const cy1 = -Math.sin(degtorad * a2) * cr + y;
        const cx2 = Math.cos(degtorad * a1) * cr + x;
        const cy2 = -Math.sin(degtorad * a1) * cr + y;

        return `M${x} ${y} ${cx1} ${cy1} A${cr} ${cr} 0 0 1 ${cx2} ${cy2}Z`;
      };

      const svgRoot = document.getElementById("svgRoot");
      const pieChartSvgString = `<svg width="${SVG_SIZE}" height="${SVG_SIZE}">
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#DD5E89;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#F7BB97;stop-opacity:1" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <g fill="url(#gradient1)">
          <path
            stroke="${STROKE}"
            strokeWidth="${STROKE_WIDTH}"
            d="${getSectorPath(SVG_SIZE / 2, SVG_SIZE / 2 - 5, DIAMETER, 45, 135)}"
          />
        </g>
        <path
          stroke="${STROKE}"
          strokeWidth="${STROKE_WIDTH}"
          d="${getSectorPath(SVG_SIZE / 2, SVG_SIZE / 2, DIAMETER, 135, 225)}"
          fill="#00ff00"
        />
        <path
          stroke="${STROKE}"
          strokeWidth="${STROKE_WIDTH}"
          d="${getSectorPath(SVG_SIZE / 2, SVG_SIZE / 2, DIAMETER, 225, 315)}"
          fill="#0000ff"
        />
        <path
          stroke="${STROKE}"
          strokeWidth="${STROKE_WIDTH}"
          d="${getSectorPath(SVG_SIZE / 2, SVG_SIZE / 2, DIAMETER, 315, 45)}"
          fill="#ffff00"
        />
      </svg>`;
      const svgNode = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(pieChartSvgString);
      svgRoot.appendChild(svgNode);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```